# Would this be the equivalent of creating a branch, while working with a detached head in Git?

Tags: version-control, git, branching

Let's say I checked out a version different than HEAD. Let's say I made some commits, and so an anonymous branch was created. Afterwards I may have checked out a different branch, so now the only way to get to my commits is via `reflog`.
If do this:

```
>> git reflog | grep -i mycommit
sha1hash
>> git branch reattaching
>> git cherry-pick hash_of_commits
>> git checkout master
>> git merge reattaching
```

Is it the equivalent of:

```
   >> git reflog | grep -i mycommit
    sha1hash
   >> git branch reattaching sha1hash
   >> git checkout master
   >> git merge reattaching
```

What happens to the detached head commits, as I think that via cherry-picking, they will exist in 2 places. Will they forever remain in my repository?

Answer (score 1):

After cherry-picking, the old commits will still be there, and won't be purged while you still have a reflog pointing at them. One of the things git-gc does is remove old entries from reflogs-- so after 60 days, or whatever, those commits will become entirely dangling and will get GC'd.